# calculating the next day from a "YYYYMMDD" formatted string

Tags: python, python-2.4

How can I calculate the next day from a string like 20110531 in the same YYYYMMDD format? In this particular case, I like to have 20110601 as the result. Calculating "tomorrow" or next day in static way is not that tough, like this:

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> (date.today() + timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20110512'
>>>
>>> (date(2011,05,31) + timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20110601'
```

But how can I use a string like `dt = "20110531"` to get the same result as above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta

t=time.strptime('20110531','%Y%m%d')
newdate=date(t.tm_year,t.tm_mon,t.tm_mday)+timedelta(1)
print newdate.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: I think you can just say `t.date()` instead of pulling the three attributes off explicitly. But, +1 for noticing that the rest of us were giving him `datetime` objects when he might have just wanted a `date`!

Comment: So, what's the advantage of using `date` over `datetime`? I far as I can see, they are doing the very same thing taking the same amount of time. Cheers!!

Comment: You used `date` in your original question, so I used it in my answer.  The question of which to use depends only on precision:  do you **need** to know the time, or just the date?

Comment: Get it now, `date` is just fine in this case. Thanks for the script, that's the on;y thing works with v2.4 so far. Cheers!!

Comment: @BrandonRhodes No `t.date()` at least in Python 2.7.

Comment: You might want to check whether your Python was compiled with all of the official modules available? The Python documentation claims that the `datetime` type's `date()` method has been available since the `datetime` module itself was added in Python 2.3: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> print datetime.strptime('20110531', '%Y%m%d')
2011-05-31 00:00:00
```

And then do math on that date object as you show in your question.

[The datetime library docs.](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)

Comment: Many thanks, that's just the thing I was looking for. I feel myself so stupid though now. Cheers!!

Comment: I'm sorry to say it's actually not working in v2.4, where actually I need to run this script. it says: `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'`. So I'm back to the base again.

Comment: Yes, AJ's answer works, only if I put theose three attributes explicitly. How to use `t.date()` instead? Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

You are most of the way there! along with the `strftime` function which converts a date to a formatted string, there is also a `strptime` function which converts back the other way.

To solve your problem you can just replace `date.today()` with `strptime(yourDateString, '%Y%m%d')`.

**ED**: and of course you will also have to add `strptime` to the end of your `from datetime import` line.

Comment: I see it works just fine without adding `strptime`. I had a look in the strptime() but didn't understand the use properly. Thanks for the comment. Cheers!!

Comment: I see your point now - it's a v2.6 vs. v2.4 issue. In v2.6, no need to import strptime. In 2.4 it reports error: `ImportError: cannot import name strptime` but `datetime.strptime()` doesn't work either.